# Error when running a flutter app in AndroidStudio: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I'm having this problem when I run a flutter App on Android Studio and I don't know how to resolve this error. Can anybody help me? When I Run it in VSCode, the running doesn't work too. The error is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBfQD.png)